# Steigerung von „falsch“

Tags: grammar, adjective

Falsch ist ein Absolutum. Aber immer wieder stoße ich auf das Problem, dass man *falsch* steigern müsste. Einfachstes Beispiel:

> Zu sagen, die Tomate sei ein Gemüse, ist falsch. Zu sagen, sie sei ein Kraftfahrzeug, ist noch „falscher“.

Ist *falsch* kontextbezogen steigerbar oder nicht?

Comment: Das ist meiner Meinung nach ein riesiges Problem der heutigen Sprache. Ich behaupte, deine Aussage ist falsch. Und zwar genauso falsch wie _Tomate=Gemüse_ UND wie _Tomate=Kraftfahrzeug_. Es ist nun einmal beides nicht richtig, da gibt es meiner Meinung nach sprachlich gesehen nichts zu diskutieren. Wenn man unbedingt eine Abstufung braucht - die, wie ich finde - semantisch nicht richtig ist, könnte man sich mit _eher falsch_ behelfen.

Comment: Abgesehen davon ist es eine ewige Diskussion, ob Tomaten denn jetzt Obst oder Gemüse sind. Vielleicht genauso ewig wie die Steigerung von absoluten Adjektiven :-)

Comment: "eher falsch" ist auf jeden Fall eine interessante rhetorische Herangehensweise.

Comment: und _falscher_ ist das nicht? ;) Abgesehen von meiner persönlichen Abneigung gegen gesteigerte absolute Adjektive, [kann|muss] ich mich schon damit abfinden, dass eine solche Steigerung in der gesprochenen Sprache vorkommt. Niedergeschrieben in einem Artikel, Roman etc. würde ich das allerdings als äußerst schlechtes Deutsch werten.

Comment: Ein anderer in diesem Zusammenhang vorkommender Zweifelsfall wird im Duden (Band 9) geklärt: Die Vergleichsformen von _falsch_ haben keinen Umlaut: _falscher, falscheste._

Comment: Zwar nicht ganz auf das Tomatenbeispiel übertragbar, aber möglicherweise auch eine hilfreiche Redewendung: "Diese Aussage ist in mehrfacher Hinsicht falsch: Erstens..... . Außerdem.... . "

Comment: Zu sagen die Tomate sei ein Gemüse ist falsch. Zu sagen sie sei ein Kraftfahrzeug ist dagegen völliger Unsinn. (Ein vernünftiger Mensch kann den ersten Fehler machen, aber nicht den zweiten).

Comment: @Loong Interessant, dass sich der Duden da anmaßt, meinem Sprachgebrauch zuwiderzulaufen ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kontextbezogen ist alles steigerbar. *Lebendiger* und *toter* gibt es ja auch. Letztlich kann man es auch als adhoc-Wortneuschöpfung oder Bedeutungserweiterung verstehen. Die meisten Absoluta können in Spezialfällen in verschiedenen Einstufungen vorkommen und somit steigerbar werden.

Solche Steigerungen sind aber mit Vorsicht zu genießen und können schlechter Stil sein, da sie eben spitzfindig wirken.

Das Beispiel ist herrlich provokativ, da Tomaten je nach Definition (botanisch/lebensmitteltechnisch) durchaus Gemüse sind. Die Klasse der Kraftfahrzeuge wäre dann aber schon etwas gedehnt..

Answer (score 5):

Vermutlich hängt die Antwort auf diese Frage auch davon ab, wie viel Wert man darauf legt, sich nicht gegen den Vorwurf wehren zu müssen, "schlechtes Deutsch" zu verwenden. In der Umgangssprache kann man *falscher* als Steigerung von *falsch* wohl noch verwenden. In einem formalen, seriösen Kontext könnte man den Sachverhalt entsprechend umschreiben und die Aussage umformulieren.

Zum Beispiel:

- Die Aussage ist *offensichtlicher falsch*
- Man macht mit dieser Aussage einen *größeren Fehler* oder *deutlicheren Fehler*
- Die Einordnung (Tomate als Kraftfahrzeug) *weicht stärker von der richtigen Einordnung ab*
- ...

Allgemeiner: Man kann statt des Wortes "falsch" ein Wort steigern, das beschreibt, **wie** falsch etwas ist (d.h. in den obigen Beispielen: *offensichtlich*, *groß*, *deutlich*, *stark* ...). Abhängig davon, worauf sich das *falsch* bezieht, gibt es dabei geeignetere oder weniger geeignete Formulierungen.

Answer (score 2):

Ich finde nicht, dass eine Steigerung hier notwendig ist, denn die eine Aussage (*Tomate = Gemüse*) ist eben genauso falsch wie die andere (*Tomate = KFZ*). Beides ist falsch.

Woran würdest Du denn quantifizieren wollen, wie falsch etwas ist? Ist es beispielsweise "noch falscher" zu sagen, eine Tomate ist ein Gebäude? Oder ist es "falscher" als *Tomate = Gemüse* aber nicht ganz so falsch wie *Tomate = KFZ*?

Manche Dinge sind aus logischer Sicht einfach nicht steigerbar. Ähnlich übrigens verhält es sich aus meiner Sicht auch mit *aktuell*. Etwas was aktuell ist, ist bereits das Neueste und es kann nichts geben, das aktueller ist, denn neuer als das Neueste geht eben nicht. Sehr wohl ist *neu* aber steigerbar. Von zwei neuen Dingen kann durchaus eines neuer sein als das andere.

Comment: Ich denke schon, dass es da Unterschiede gibt. Gemüse und Obst ist immerhin artverwandt. Auch dein Beispiel gibt hier Interpretationsspielraum. Eine SMS von heut morgen, bzw deren Inhalt ist "aktueller", als eine Nachricht, die du vor 2 Jahren empfangen hast.

Comment: Wenn die Information aus der SMS von vor 2 Jahren überholt ist, dann ist sie nicht aktuell, sondern die Information aus der heutigen SMS ist aktuell. Beinhalten beide den gleichen Informationsstand sind beide Informationen aktuell, aber die eine SMS ist neuer. Sobald Du den Drang verspürst, eine Sache als "aktueller" als etwas anderes zu bezeichnen, ist die andere Sache veraltet und damit nicht mehr aktuell. Es gibt also keinen Grund, "aktueller" überhaupt zu verwenden - außer um reißerisch so zu tun, als hätte man bessere Verkehrsinfos als alle anderen...

Answer (score 1):

Sprachphilosophisch [nicht ganz korrekt](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Familien%C3%A4hnlichkeit) kann man die Aussage *X ist ein A* dann als wahr/richtig ansehen, wenn *A* eine endliche Anzahl *n* notwendiger Eigenschaften aufweist, die *X* alle erfüllt. Die Aussage ist entsprechend unwahr/falsch, wenn es bei mindestens einer Eigenschaft eine Abweichung gibt. 
Für *n* > 1 kann man durchaus sagen, dass eine Aussage umso falscher ist je weniger der notwendigen Eigenschaften sie erfüllt. 
Man sollte aber die Umkehrung vermeiden, d.h. die Aussage ist nicht wahrer/richtiger (sondern nur weniger falsch) je mehr der notwendigen Eigenschaften sie erfüllt, solange es nicht alle sind. Eventuell kann man *wahr* oder *richtig* dann sinnvoll steigern, wenn es optionale [prototypische](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototypensemantik) Eigenschaften gibt, die erfüllt sein können.

Answer (score 1):

Umgangssprachlich kann man auf jeden Fall von einer *fälscheren Aussage* oder den *fälschesten Vorstellungen* reden. Dass das allerdings ausschließlich auf gesprochene Umgangssprache (oder geschriebene Umgangssprache wie in Chats, SMS o.ä.) beschränkt bleiben sollte, ergibt sich schon daran, dass nicht einmal über die Form Einigkeit herrscht: Alle anderen Antworten bisher schlagen *falscher* vor, für mich müsste es *fälscher* lauten.

Demnach: Im Gespräch völlig in Ordnung, in einer Rede als Stilmittel wahrscheinlich auch noch; in einem Brief oder Aufsatz sollte man die Form tunlichst vermeiden. Andere Antworten haben viele mögliche alternative Formulierungen aufgezeigt.