# Was heißt »nicht steig.« in einem Wörterbuch?

Tags: meaning, terminology, abbreviation, dictionary

Ich schlage die Wörter, die ich nicht weiß, in einem [Online-Wörterbuch](http://de.thefreedictionary.com) nach. Bei der Bedeutung mancher Wörter steht ***nicht steig.***, aber es sagt mir nichts.

Die Website selbst hat keine Erklärung dafür (oder ich konnte sie nicht finden).

Beispiele

- > **unterschwellig**
  >  unterschwellig **nicht steig.** psych.: so, dass es nicht bewusst wird unterschwellige Ängste/Abneigungen
- > **benutzbar**
  >  benutzbar benützbar **nicht steig.** zum Benutzen geeignet *Dieses
  >   Gerät ist nicht mehr benutzbar.* Benutzbarkeit, Benützbarkeit

Was meint das Wörterbuch damit?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"Nicht steig." ist die Abkürzung für

> Nicht steigerbar.

Bei den betreffenden Adjektiven oder Adverbien ist eine Steigerung üblicherweise nicht sinnvoll. Beispielsweise gibt es keinen Komparativ oder Superlativ zu dreieckig: "dreieckiger" oder "am dreieckigsten" ergibt keinen Sinn.

**EDIT:** Wie im Kommentar genannt ist der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/unterschwellig) übrigens der Ansicht, dass "unterschwellig" sehr wohl steigerbar ist. "Benutzbar" hingegen ist auch laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/benutzbar) nicht steigerbar.

Comment: Richtige Antwort, auch wenn ich an der Aussage gerade bei den genannten Beispielen meine Zweifel habe. Wieso kann einem eine Sache nicht noch weniger bewusst werden als eine andere? Und dafür, dass es mit [ux.se] sogar eine eigene SE-Seite gibt, die sich um das Thema dreht, wie man **die Benutzbarkeit steigern** kann, ist es schon interessant, dass das Adjektiv *benutzbar* nicht gesteigert werden soll.

Comment: Der Duden gibt übrigens Steigerungsformen von "unterschwellig" an. Umgangssprachlich könnte ich mir einen Satz wie "Du musst das schon etwas unterschwelliger rüberbringen!" durchaus vorstellen.

Comment: Ich habe gedacht, dass ich eine neue Frage stellen soll aber ich habe die Antwort hier gefunden: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/28081/steigerung-von-falsch

Comment: "unterschwelliger" macht genauso viel Sinn wie "schwangerer" oder "toter" ... der spinnt, der Duden.

Comment: @tink z.B Ich war schon tot bevor du mich verlassen hast, nachdem ich gehört habe, dass du ihn heiraten wirst, jetzt bin ich mich toter.  Oder ein anderes Beispiel: (als Hypnotiseur sage ich in einer Anzeige) ich habe bisher Ihre unterschwelligen Ängste endeckt. Mit meiner neuen Methode kann ich jetzt noch unterschwelligeren Ängste entdecken.

Comment: @tink Ich meine man kann alle Adjektiven und Adverben figurativ steigern.

Comment: @AdInfinitum Ich denke, man kann sich —figurativ — lebloser fühlen als zuvor, aber toter sein als zuvor geht selbst im übertragenen Sinne schwer. Einfach, weil "tot" toter ist als "leblos" (immer noch auf figurativer Ebene). Und hoppla, hier ist "toter" auf einmal richtig. — Der Kern ist aber glaube ich, dass man nicht "schon tot war bevor man verlassen wurde". Aber jemand anders kann für mich "tot sein", obwohl er lebt (=> Er interessiert mich nicht). "Leblos fühlen" bedeutet aber soviel wie energielos, "tot" ist tot.

Comment: @Em1 Ich habe einige Zitate gefunden. Hier wird die Steigerungsformen von *tot* verwendet. *Vor dreißig Jahren hat ein Toter einem noch Toteren die Hand in den Hosenstall gesteckt.*
(Anne Enright, „Das Familientreffen“, übersetzt von Hans-Christian Oeser) oder *Den Rest des Jahres herrscht kulturell toteste Hose*

Comment: @Em1 Logischerweise ist man tot oder nicht aber -figurativ- kann man alles machen.